# how to rejoin Mon and mgr Ceph to cluster

Tags: ceph

i have this situation and cand access to ceph dashboard.i haad 5 mon but 2 of them went down and one of them is the bootstrap mon node so that have mgr and I got this from that node.

```
    2020-10-14T18:59:46.904+0330 7f9d2e8e9700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2,1]
  cluster:
    id:     e97c1944-e132-11ea-9bdd-e83935b1c392
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            no active mgr

  services:
    mon: 3 daemons, quorum srv4,srv5,srv6 (age 2d)
    mgr: no daemons active (since 2d)
    mds: heyatfs:1 {0=heyfs.srv10.lxizhc=up:active} 1 up:standby
    osd: 54 osds: 54 up (since 47h), 54 in (since 3w)

  task status:
    scrub status:
        mds.heyfs.srv10.lxizhc: idle

  data:
    pools:   3 pools, 65 pgs
    objects: 223.95k objects, 386 GiB
    usage:   1.2 TiB used, 97 TiB / 98 TiB avail
    pgs:     65 active+clean

  io:
    client:   105 KiB/s rd, 328 KiB/s wr, 0 op/s rd, 0 op/s wr
```

I have to say the whole story, I used cephadm to create my cluster at first and I'm so new to ceph i have 15 servers and 14 of them have OSD container and 5 of them had mon and my bootstrap mon that is srv2 have mgr.
2 of these servers have public IP and I used one of them as a client (I know this structure have a lot of question in it but my company forces me to do it and also I'm new to ceph so it's how it's now). 2 weeks ago I lost 2 OSD and I said to datacenter who gives me these servers to change that 2 HDD they restart those servers and unfortunately, those servers were my Mon server. after they restarted those servers on of them came back srv5 but I could see srv3 is out of quorum
so i begon to solve this problem so I used this command in ceph shell --fsid ...

```
ceph orch apply mon srv3
ceph mon remove srv3
```

after some while I see in my dashboard srv2 my boostrap mon and mgr is not working and when I used ceph -s ssrv2 isn't there and I can see srv2 mon in removed directory

```
root@srv2:/var/lib/ceph/e97c1944-e132-11ea-9bdd-e83935b1c392# ls
crash  crash.srv2  home  mgr.srv2.xpntaf  osd.0  osd.1  osd.2  osd.3  removed
```

but mgr.srv2.xpntaf is running and unfortunately, I lost my access to ceph dashboard now

i tried to add srv2 and 3 to monmap with

```
  576  ceph orch daemon add mon srv2:172.32.X.3
  577  history | grep dump
  578  ceph mon dump
  579  ceph -s
  580  ceph mon dump
  581  ceph mon add srv3 172.32.X.4:6789
```

and now

```
root@srv2:/# ceph -s
  cluster:
    id:     e97c1944-e132-11ea-9bdd-e83935b1c392
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            no active mgr
            2/5 mons down, quorum srv4,srv5,srv6

  services:
    mon: 5 daemons, quorum srv4,srv5,srv6 (age 16h), out of quorum: srv2, srv3
    mgr: no daemons active (since 2d)
    mds: heyatfs:1 {0=heyatfs.srv10.lxizhc=up:active} 1 up:standby
    osd: 54 osds: 54 up (since 2d), 54 in (since 3w)

  task status:
    scrub status:
        mds.heyatfs.srv10.lxizhc: idle

  data:
    pools:   3 pools, 65 pgs
    objects: 223.95k objects, 386 GiB
    usage:   1.2 TiB used, 97 TiB / 98 TiB avail
    pgs:     65 active+clean

  io:
    client:   105 KiB/s rd, 328 KiB/s wr, 0 op/s rd, 0 op/s wr
```

and I must say `ceph orch host ls` doesn't work and it hangs when I run it and I think it's because of that err no active mgr and also when I see that removed directory mon.srv2 is there and you can see unit.run file so I used that command to run the container again but it says mon.srv2 isn't on mon map and doesn't have specific IP and by the way I must say after `ceph orch apply mon srv3` i could see a new container with a new fsid in srv3 server

I now my whole problem is because I ran this command `ceph orch apply mon srv3`
because when you see the installation document :

To deploy monitors on a specific set of hosts:

```
# ceph orch apply mon *<host1,host2,host3,...>*
```

**Be sure to include the first (bootstrap) host in this list.**

and I didn't see that line !!!

now I manage to have another mgr running but I got this

```
root@srv2:/var/lib/ceph/mgr# ceph -s
2020-10-15T13:11:59.080+0000 7f957e9cd700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2,1]
  cluster:
    id:     e97c1944-e132-11ea-9bdd-e83935b1c392
    health: HEALTH_ERR
            1 stray daemons(s) not managed by cephadm
            2 mgr modules have failed
            2/5 mons down, quorum srv4,srv5,srv6

  services:
    mon: 5 daemons, quorum srv4,srv5,srv6 (age 20h), out of quorum: srv2, srv3
    mgr: srv4(active, since 8m)
    mds: heyatfs:1 {0=heyatfs.srv10.lxizhc=up:active} 1 up:standby
    osd: 54 osds: 54 up (since 2d), 54 in (since 3w)

  task status:
    scrub status:
        mds.heyatfs.srv10.lxizhc: idle

  data:
    pools:   3 pools, 65 pgs
    objects: 301.77k objects, 537 GiB
    usage:   1.6 TiB used, 97 TiB / 98 TiB avail
    pgs:     65 active+clean

  io:
    client:   180 KiB/s rd, 597 B/s wr, 0 op/s rd, 0 op/s wr
```

and when I run the `ceph orch host ls` i see this

```
root@srv2:/var/lib/ceph/mgr# ceph orch host ls
HOST   ADDR          LABELS  STATUS
srv10  172.32.x.11
srv11  172.32.x.12
srv12  172.32.x.13
srv13  172.32.x.14
srv14  172.32.x.15
srv15  172.32.x.16
srv2   srv2
srv3   172.32.x.4
srv4   172.32.x.5
srv5   172.32.x.6
srv6   172.32.x.7
srv7   172.32.x.8
srv8   172.32.x.9
srv9   172.32.x.10
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would suggest to start with restarting the containers. But if only the containers are down you should see the cluster status showing 5 mon daemons not 3. So did you somehow remove the other mon containers? Did you run something like `ceph orch apply -i file.yml`? Did you change the placement so the orchestrator remove nodes? More details are required.

Comment: I have to say the whole story, so I edit my above help request

Comment: Although I'm not sure I get all the steps but this doesn't seem to be a big issue. MGR role is uncritical, you can simply assign that role to the existing MONs and run `ceph orch apply mgr ...` also for several nodes so you have multiple MGRs, one of them will be active and your dashboard will be available again. As for the MONs you should either figure out why the srv2 and srv3 containers won't start (`cephadm logs --name <NAME>`) or you just wipe them (carefully!!) and recreate them. As long as you have a quorum your cluster will be available to clients.

Comment: I know that but I have limits one of them is orch doesn't do anything and hangs when I use it and 2 is I need a dashboard on public environment because ( I said I have 2 servers with public IP in that datacenter one of them is a client and one of them was srv2 my bootstrap mon and mgr and I had only  1 mgr and it's another problem I figure it out now, my whole network are in another datacenter )

Comment: You could be right, having no mgr would result in unavailable orch module (since it's a manager module). I'm not too deep in ceph with containers yet, but you could setup a non-containerized mgr service temporarily and go from there (https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/mgr/administrator/#mgr-administrator-guide).

Comment: for now, I have another question srv4 5 6 have a private IP address and i can connect to them through srv2 i must have ssh connection to srv2 then in srv2 run another ssh to srv4 5 6 now if i create another mgr for example on srv4 I think I couldn't' see another dashboard because it's on private IP or not i can see it with srv2 public IP ? and if I run another mgr can I  run another mon on srv2 and then change primary mgr to srv2 ?

Comment: I wouldn't focus on the dashboard but rather fix the environment. After you have an active MGR you can redeploy more MGR services on the dedicated servers and then your dashboard will also be available again.

Comment: okey now i have somthing that i append to above question I could manage to add another mgr @eblock

Comment: okay finally with you advise I can manage it and my ceph is back with health ok message

Comment: The stray daemon is obviously the one you created manually. Now you should add more mgr daemons the orchestrator way like I wrote before. And after you have successfully deployed containerized mgr daemons you remove the one you created manually. One step at a time...